# "Best" way to get an Outlook MailItem from .msg file

Tags: c#, outlook

To pass from a .msg file to its related Outlook MailItem I found and tried these two ways:

```
Outlook.Application oApp; // --> Outlook Application
Outlook.MailItem oItem; // --> Outlook MailItem
string file= @"C:\PWS\myMail.msg";
oApp= (Outlook.Application)new Outlook.Application();

// way #1
oItem= (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(file);
// or way #2
oItem= (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(file);
```

What is the difference between these two ways? I need to open the .msg and then use the resulting MailItem (to get some properties as 'SenderEmailAddress' or the email attachments)... what should I use? At the moment they are the same to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third way is to use run .msg file programmatically. A default application (outlook) should be opened in that case. For example:

```
 string file= @"C:\PWS\myMail.msg";
 Process.Run(file);
```

Be aware, you can't run multiple instance of Outlook. So, the message will be opened in the existing Outlook instance (if any).

Both methods (#1 and #2) allow to open the saved message in Outlook. But they have minor differences:

The [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865637.aspx) method of the Application class **creates a new** Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) and returns the new item. I'd also like to draw your attention to the fact that new items will always open in compose mode, as opposed to read mode, regardless of the mode in which the items were saved to disk.

The [OpenSharedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.openshareditem.aspx) method of the Namespace class **opens a shared item** from a specified path or URL. See [How to: Import Saved Items using OpenSharedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176433%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

It is up to you which way to choose based on the information listed above...